# Sublime Text Keybinds Context Within Unsaved Changes

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext, key-bindings

I am trying to create a keybind within sublime text 3 that **changes its behavior depending if a file has unsaved changes** or not.

Sublime already supports a **context** option within the creation of keybinds such as this:

```
{"keys":[":","e"],"command":"revert","context":[{"key": "setting.command_mode", "operand": true}]},
```

However I can't find if there is a way to detect if the file is saved or dirty.

Anyone have some insights on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the [unofficial documentation](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/key_bindings.html#context-operands) (the official documentation is out-of-date), there seems to be no context that can be used in keybindings to determine if a file is saved or dirty.

I think it would therefore be necessary to create a plugin in Python, with a command which would perform the actions you require based on whether the file has unsaved changes or not.  You could then set the keybinding to execute this command regardless of context, as the plugin will contain the necessary logic.
The [official documentation](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/api_reference.html#sublime.View) mentions that a plugin can determine whether a file is saved or not using the `is_dirty()` method on the view.

I see from your question that you want to execute the revert command, so I have drawn up a quick and simple Sublime Text plugin / python script that will achieve this:

```
import sublime, sublime_plugin

class RevertIfUnsavedCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit):
        if self.view.is_dirty():
            self.view.run_command('revert')
        else:
            print('TODO: do something else here')
```